# Can't manage to submit images to WordPress post from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, file, frontend

I'm working with WordPress with a custom template I made from scratch, and I don't want to use external plugins.

I have a frontend form that allows users to upload posts which is currently working.

I added an option to upload an image and set it as thumbnail, which also works fine.

Now I want to add the option to upload images, and to attach them to the post content so I can later show the post with the images and the content in single.php

this is how the html looks right now:

```
<?php new_post(); ?>
<form class="col-sm-12 col-md-5" id="new_post" name="new_post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                
                    <p>Título de la publicación:</p>
                        <input type="text" id="titulo" value="" size="20" name="titulo" />
                    
                    <p>Imagen principal de la publicación:</p>
                        <input class="selector-archivo" type="file" name="imagen-post" id="imagen-post" >
                    
                    <p>Agregar imágenes a la publicación:</p>

                    <input class="selector-archivo" type="file" name="fotosVehiculo[]" id="fotosVehiculo[]" multiple />

                    <div id="upload-image-container"></div>
                    
                    <p>Tipo de vehículo: 
                        <select name="select_vehiculo" class="listado-filtro">
                            <option disabled selected value>Elija un vehículo...</option>
                            <?php 
                
                            $postTypes = get_post_types('', 'objects');
                                foreach ($postTypes as $postType) {
                                    if ($postType->labels->es_vehiculo == '1') {
                                        $name = $postType->labels->name;    
                                        echo '<option>' . $name . '</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </p>
            
                    <p>Marca: 
                        <select name="select_marca" class="listado-filtro">
                        <option disabled selected value>Elija una marca...</option>
                        <?php 
                            $taxonomy = array('taxonomy' => 'marcas_y_modelos');
                            $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                            foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                                    $term = $tax_term->name;
                                    echo '<option value="' . $term . '">' . $term . '</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>Descripción: </p>
                        <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
                    
                    <p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publicar" id="publicar" name="publicar" />
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post', 'nonce-checker'); ?>
                </form>
```

and this is the function that handles everything:

```
    function new_post() { 
    
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {
        if ( !isset( $_POST['nonce-checker'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce-checker'], 'new-post' ) ) {

                wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); 
                exit;  

            } else {

                

            //validations...
            if (isset ($_POST['titulo'])) {
                $title =  trim($_POST['titulo']);
            } else {
                echo 'Por favor inserte un título';
            }
                    if (isset ($_POST['descripcion'])) {
                $description = trim($_POST['descripcion']);
            } else {
                echo 'Por favor inserte el contenido';
            }
                    if (isset ($_POST['select_vehiculo'])) {
                $vehiculo = $_POST['select_vehiculo'];
                $vehiculo = sanitizeFiltro($vehiculo);
            } else {
                echo 'Por favor elija un tipo de vehículo';
            }
                    if (isset ($_POST['select_marca'])) {
                $marca = $_POST['select_marca'];
                $marca = sanitizeFiltro($marca);
            } else {
                echo 'Por favor elija una marca';
            }
                    
            $post = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $description,
                'post_category' => array('marcas_y_modelos'),
                'tax_input' => array('marcas_y_modelos' => $marca ),
                'post_status'   => 'publish',           
                'post_type' => $vehiculo, 
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $marca, 'marcas_y_modelos', true);

            if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            }

            if ($_FILES) {

                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                    }
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
                    if ($file['imagen-post']) {
                        update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
                    }
                }   
            } else {
                echo '<hr><p style="color:red">No se cargaron imágenes</p><hr>';
            }
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Alta') ) ); 
            exit;  
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the images are not being uploaded at all and I can't understand why, I've tried a lot of possible solutions, but none worked. Please I need a tested solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens? Can you isolate the point of failure? Does the image make it to the back-end in the `$_FILES` array? Does `media_handle_upload()` return a value? Is it failing on `update_post_meta()`?

Comment: well the post content gets uploaded, the post thumbnail gets uploaded too ("imagen-post"), but if i add more images through "fotosvehiculo[]" input, they wont upload at all... when i do a var_dump on get_attached_media() after the post is uploaded, i can see that only the thumbnails gets uploaded..
Anyways, i've started from scratch with the help of another post here and now its working, i think my problem was on 
    if ($_FILES) {

                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
because i was sending an array and it was expecting a file, maybe?

Comment: Oh, yah I didn't catch that, you may be misunderstanding the foreach syntax. It should be `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`. As you created it the `$file` variable will just be holding the string key, while `$array` will hold the value you're actually trying to work with.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: i just realized i never answered back.. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't understanding the foreach syntax. As dave [mentions in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784517/cant-manage-to-submit-images-to-wordpress-post-from-frontend/63157848#comment86615802_49784517)

> Oh, yah I didn't catch that, you may be misunderstanding the foreach syntax. It should be `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`. As you created it the `$file` variable will just be holding the string key, while `$array` will hold the value you're actually trying to work with. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php